# Prove or disprove the following results

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This question appeared in ISI MStat 2004 sample paper.

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions such that $f(x)\leq g(x) \forall x\in [0,1]$.  Determine which of the following statements are true or false.

For all $x \in [0,1]$:

a) $\int_0^x |f(t)|\,dt \leq\int_0^x |g(t)|\,dt$

b) $\int_0^x (|f(t)|+f(t))\,dt\leq\int_0^x (|g(t)|+g(t))\,dt$

c) $\int_0^x (|f(t)|-f(t))\,dt \leq\int_0^x (|g(t)|-g(t))\,dt$

Prove it if it is true or give counter-example.

I found for $f(x)=-x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ the result a) is false. But I cannot think how to add those integration to claim something. If you can help me visualize that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Some issue in the typesetting of the question with respect to the function $g$ in each of the parts. Please look up MathJax to complete the rest of the question. Even without that, fair to say that $f \leq g$ need not imply $|f| \leq |g|$, so constant functions served up a good counterexample there.

Comment: What's with the Euros?

Comment: Yea corrected it, I'm newb in mathjax. Thanks for replying

Comment: You can see easily, that a) is false for $f(x)=-1$ and $g(x)=0$.

Comment: I found result a) is false. But what about the rest of them?